# Can I directly access data on a harddrive removed from failed Drobo device?

Tags: external-hard-drive, drobo

I have a Drobo network storage device that's 5+ years old. The device might be fully functional but lately I have not been able to connect to it from my Win10 machine: Drobo Dashboard is not seeing the disks. Have been troubleshooting the issue including contacting Drobo support but so far no luck.

If I take it apart, and try to connect one of the disks to my computer via a simple HDD USB enclosure (e.g. like [**this**](https://www.microcenter.com/product/486116/inland-35-usb-30-hard-drive-enclosure)), will I be able to see the data on it? Do I need a specific type of enclosure?

TIA!

Comment: "If I take it apart, and try to connect one of the disks to my computer via a simple HDD USB enclosure (e.g. like this), will I be able to see the data on it?" - No;  You would have to connect all your disks in order to do this.  "Do I need a specific type of enclosure?" - Since Drobo uses like own RAID solution you won't be able to simply attach your disks to your system without using an actual Drobo device.  There are third-party services who have developed techniques to recover data from Drobo devices.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you. Not what I wanted to hear but oh well...